# read csv file(numeric type) in scala

Tags: scala, csv, readfile

I would like to read csv file in scala.

[image]

```
  val rows = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()

      using(io.Source.fromFile("test.csv")) { source =>
        for (line <- source.getLines) {
          rows += line.split(",").map(_.trim)
          }
        }     
      def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
         try {
            f(resource)
         }finally {
            resource.close()
            }
```

I used above code to read csv file.

I get ArrayBuffer(Array[String]) now, but I want to get ArrayBuffer(Array[Double]).

toDouble method is wrong

What's the ideal way to do?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toDouble` is right, just call it on strings.

```
rows.map(_.map(_.toDouble))
```

Or right in your code

```
using(io.Source.fromFile("test.csv")) { source =>
  for (line <- source.getLines) {
    rows += line.split(",").map(_.trim).map(_.toDouble)
  }
}
```

To avoid mutable collections you could use lists, like this:

```
val rows: List[List[Double]] = using(io.Source.fromFile("test.csv")) { source =>
  source.getLines.toList map { line =>
    line.split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble).toList
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against parsing CSV manually, you'll most likely eventually encounter one of the annoying edge cases (values with lines or columns separators, for instance). It's often better and safer to use dedicated libraries.

I'm going to recommend [kantan.csv](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv) because I'm the author, but there are plenty other quality libraries out there (product-collections, pure csv...).

With kantan.csv, your problem would be solved thusly:

```
import kantan.csv.ops._

// For an immutable structure.
new java.io.File("test.csv").readCsv[List, List[Double]](',', false)

// For an Array, as in your example.
new java.io.File("test.csv").readCsv[Array, Array[Double]](',', false)
```